# Random switching between "mobile" and "normal" versions of the site

Tags: bug

Since registering at Space Exploration Stack Exchange few months ago (I've been always using browser of mobile phone to access the site, I.e. no computer or laptop), I was able to see only a "mobile" version, i.e. such things as question views, user account statistics, tags statistics, text formatting tools and text preview when asking a question etc. were unavailable.

Then roughly a month later it suddenly started to show a "normal" version (In the same browser, in the same mobile phone).

Yesterday it somehow randomly switched back to a "mobile" version again (I didn't change anything). So the site now looks like this:
[image]

1) What might be the cause of this seemingly random switching (i.e. could it be related to the site itself, or maybe the problem lies in the browser of my mobile phone), and

<s>2) is there a way I could access again the "normal" version of the site from my mobile device?</s>

---

Update:
Today I have discovered a "button" in my mobile browser which toggles between "mobile version" and "desktop version" of the page (which I never knew had existed), so the point #2 above is more or less solved.

But when I choose the "desktop" version now, although it includes all the features, it looks differently (formatting is not adapted to mobile and text size of certain comments is more than twice smaller than the others) to what it used to be few weeks ago (i.e. to what I called a "normal" version above), being presumably just an advanced variant of mobile version, since I have never manually toggled the version to "desktop" in my browser until today).

One of the reasonable hypotheses I have is that it might have been a roughly one-month long test of an advanced mobile version (with subsequent roll back to the previous not-so-advanced mobile version, happened yesterday). In any case,  the change (which happened twice) of the look of mobile versions (or whichever variants they in fact were) wasn't induced by myself on purpose (it somehow happened automatically).

Comment: You're not using the Stack Exchange app I take it.  Sometimes it randomly links out to Stack Exchange pages in the browser...

Comment: @OrganicMarble No, not App. I'm using just a standard browser in the smartphone.